# Location data in images captured with Android

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have a requirement of locating the latitude, longitude, time and date of a picture which is taken by the camera of an Android phone.

What can I utilize to obtain this data?

Comment: sorry for the trouble. I got the required information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting latitude, longitude use

```
public void find_Location(Context con)
{
    this.con=con;
    String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)con.getSystemService(location_context);

    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
   for (String provider : providers) 
   {
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,new LocationListener()
       {
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
           public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
           public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle  extras){}
       });
       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
       if (location != null)
       {
           latitude = location.getLatitude();
           longitude = location.getLongitude();
       } 
   }
}
}
```

For Time and Date use java Date class.